# convert json_encode php to javascript but without double quotes

Tags: javascript, php

here is the output of a php json_encode() call:

```
//start
//docStructure version 1.0.alpha compiled September 16th, 2014 at 9:18PM
var docStructure={"updateTime":"2014-09-16 21:18:19","listeners":[{"name":"eFaxListener","active":"0","url":"?action=faxvcheckinboundfax"}],"sections":{"defaultLayout":{"header":[]}},"editors":{"sideeditor":{"state":"closed","width":"0","context":""}}}//end
```

note the keys all have double quotes around them.

I would prefer to have the keys NOT have double quotes for easier reading.  Is there any difference?  I would prefer to identify as

```
alert(docStructure.editors.siteeditor.state);
```

vs.

```
alert(docStructure['editors']['siteeditor']['state'])
```

Or can I stil use these interchangeably with the keys as strings?

Thanks, this is building my understanding of javascript's thinking..

Comment: You can use either access method above. The quotes around the keys don't make any difference to you when you use them

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) requires the keys to be double quoted, once parsed by javascript its just a normal object, so you can access them both ways, assuming your keys are valid object keys(not starting with a number or a special character).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [**jQuery.parseJSON( json )**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/eJSON/)

**Description:**

*Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.*